# Access google Maps API in nokia series 40

Tags: google-maps-api-3, java-me, nokia-s40

I want to access the Google map API  in series 40 mobiles. I tried with using http connection but the map displayed statically. I want to load the map and moving the location in the map so that I have to use the Google map dynamically.

Please give an idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) site does not contain a specific SDK for JavaME (or Series 40). The static Maps API can be used, but only for static images (no dynamic panning or zooming).

A good alternative is to use Nokia's [HERE Maps](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!index.html). Its API is designed to work with JavaME and it offers a dynamic experience in Series 40 devices. [Code Examples](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!code-examples.html) are also available and seem to be quite comprehensive, including panning, zoom and different map types.

PS: I'm not affiliated with Nokia in any way. I do use Here Maps on my Nokia quite frequently and I find it a good mapping solution.

EDIT: I got the Nokia HERE Maps working on a Java SDK1.1 emulator doing the following:

1. Download the Nokia Asha SDK 1.0. This (HUGE) download contains the most up to date libraries.
2. Create a new JavaME project using the Java SDK 1.1.
3. Sign in to HERE Maps and create an App Id and Token.
4. Add the following code in your MIDlet.

   ```
   public class MapMIDlet extends MIDlet {
       protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
           ApplicationContext.getInstance().setAppID("API IP");
           ApplicationContext.getInstance().setToken("API TOKEN");

           Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);
           MapCanvas mapCanvas = new MapCanvas(display){
               public void onMapUpdateError(String description, 
                   Throwable detail, boolean critical) {
                   // Error handling goes here.
               }
               public void onMapContentComplete() {
               }
           };

           mapCanvas.getMapDisplay().setState(
               new MapDisplayState(new GeoCoordinate(52.51, 13.4, 0), 10));
           display.setCurrent(mapCanvas);
       } 
   }
   ```
5. Reference the maps-core.jar located in "C:\Nokia\Devices\Nokia_Asha_SDK_1_0\plugins\maps api\lib".
6. Clean the project and run. This should display a basic pannable and zoomable map.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I know the here maps API used for nokia series 40 devices. I am developing for nokia asha 300 and sdk is nokia sdk 1.0 for java(series 40 developer platform 1.0) . In this sdk map jars are not found. Nokia supports map API in series 40 developer platform 2.0. Is it right. Please help me .

Comment: [This document](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!index.html;#toc_Devicecompatibility) says that the only dependencies are CLDC1.1 and MIDP2.0, so it should work. I'll try to figure something out when I get home later.

Comment: @seipl, I updated the answer with a solution. Does it work for you?