# how to access the google map API dynamically in j2me

Tags: google-maps, java-me

I have to include the google map API in j2me application. I want to change the route and change the center position dynamically. I have searched a lot. Now I am using google static map API but it shows the image statically. I want to show the map dynamically.

```
   Using javascript API v3  shall I implement google map API in j2me. But one of forums I have found we can't use javascript API in j2me application. Please Give clear idea about this why we can't implement in j2me.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken a deeper look, but I found these two links when searching Google.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived:Google_Static_Maps_API_in_Java_ME
http://www.jappit.com/blog/midmaps-google-maps-java-me-library/

Answer (score 0):

Whereas it is technically possible to use a static mapping API to display an map in Java ME, If you want to **dynamically** update the map, you would be much better off using a library which uses a tile server, caches your map tiles and overlays objects on top of it.

This should result in a **much** lower data traffic overhead as explained [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_the_RESTful_Map_API_with_Java_ME#Comparision_of_Network_traffic_generated_by_the_RESTful_Map_API_and_Maps_API_for_Java_ME). Only use a Map Image API if  all you need is a **single** map image.

The dynamic mapping library I would suggest is Nokia's [HERE Maps API for Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME), as you can tell from the name, the API is specifically designed to work with Java ME devices.

The API is currently bundled with the Nokia Asha SDK 1.0, but despite this, it is in reality a separate **independent** plugin and has been designed to work with the full range of standard Java ME devices.

A similar Stack Overflow question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080047/access-google-maps-api-in-nokia-series-40/17098990#17098990) describes how to download it.

As a notice of affiliation, I should mention in passing that I do work for Nokia.